# Debugging python script called by Process Builder in Intellij

Tags: java, python, debugging, intellij-idea

I am running a python script `Test.py` which is a local file to my Intellij project.  I invoke it in `ProcessBuilder`:

```
 static void runPython() throws IOException {

        ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder("python", "Test.py");
        pb2.directory(new File(baseDir));
        pb2.redirectInput(new File(debugFile));

        Process p2 = pb2.start();

    }
```

The script is a simple implementation of insertion sort.  With my current Intellij configuration I get some code highlighting and completion.  When I place a breakpoint on the python code and run my app in debug mode it does not enter the break point.  This makes sense because it won't enter the breakpoint even with java code because it is a subprocess.

However, under preference -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Python Debugger,  I check "Attach to sub-process automatically while debugging".  This does not seem to work.

I am wondering if I need to install any additional plugin software or make any configuration changes to be able to debug python code run from Process Builder instances.

It is important to debug the python script as invoked by my java code as particular standard input is being sent to it in this way which is what i'm trying to debug.

Comment: Here's an alternative suggestion. In the terminal: `pip install asdb`. In the python code, insert `import asdb; asdb.set_trace()`. Run the Java code. Run `asdb` in the terminal and you should enter a simple `pdb`-like debugger.

Comment: im getting a lengthy error log in terminal after running the pip install asdb ending in "--compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/cg/wpj8zdx96k579fzzkm4scdfc0000gn/T/pip-build-asc7Ez/rpdb"

Comment: works, but a little confusing with all the (pdb)(pdb) any quick guides on using it?

Comment: Type `help` or google "python pdb"

Comment: What does it mean to 'run asdb' in the terminal?